# How do I keep events elements added through a ajax call in jQuery "active"

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, jquery-events

I'm placing content on my page through an ajax (post) request like so:

```
$("input#ViewMore").click(function() {
            var data = { before: oldestDate, threadId: 1 };
            $.post("/Message/More", data,function(html) {
                $('tbody#posts').prepend(html);
                return false;
            },
            "html");
            return false;
        });
```

with the html coming back looking something like:

```
<div id="comment">Message output <a href="#" id="quote">Quote</a></div>
```

This is all working fine and dandy, everything appears as it should, no problems.

The problem occurs when I have an event hooked into the "quote" anchor that has been added through the ajax call.  Specifically, a jQuery event on that anchor does not fire.  Why?

For instance:

```
$("#quote).click(function() { ... });
```

Does nothing.  Acts like there is no event on it.  I know it is working on other anchors on the page that were not added through a ajax request, so there is not a code error there, plus if I refresh the page it will then fire correctly.  Is there some reason that this is happening, do I need someway to reinitialize that event on the anchor tag somehow?  Any ideas?

Working with jQuery 1.3.1 (didn't work with 1.2.6 either) so I believe it is my implementation not code itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Events/live](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live) of jQuery 1.3, *live* will bind a handler to an event for all current - and future - matched elements.

Answer (score 2):

When the new content is added to the page with Ajax you have to re-register all the events to those new elements.

Comment: how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Changed to

```
$('#quote').live("click", function() { ... }
```

and

```
$("input#ViewMore").live("click", function() { ... }
```

Doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

CMS's answer helped, but here's how it ended up:

The view more button event remained the same as it was outside of the AJAH request that added it:

```
$("input#ViewMore").click( function() { ... }
```

Elements that had events that were being added in and out of the AJAH request needed to use the live method:

```
$('#quote').live("click", function() { ... }
```

Works like a charm!